# How to select text between integers and unit names in Sublime Text 3 with regex?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext, regex-lookarounds

The goal is to select text between integers and unit names in Sublime Text 3 with regex. I thought this way: first select integers and unit names, then just choose everything between them:

```
(?<=(1))(2)(?=(3))
```

Regexp #1 should capture integers, regexp #3 should capture needed unit names, regexp #2 just captures all between these two groups.

Here are the expressions i wrote:

1. `(((?<=\d)([-−,*\s]|(X·))(?=\d))|(\d))+`
2. `(.{1,10}?)`
3. `((?<=\d)|(?<=\b))(моль|мкм|мф|нм|лм|кг|кд|Гц|Кл|К|Дж|Вт|м|с|ф|А)(?=\b)`

#1 and #3 works ok, a combination of #2 and #3 works too, but #1 + #2 and #1 + #2 + #3 doesnt work and the reason is error "Invalid lookbehind assertion encountered in regular expression". Thus i think the error is in the first group: `(?<=(1))`. If you insert my #1 in it, the whole expression will look like this:

```
(?<=((((?<=\d)([-−,*\s]|(X·))(?=\d))|(\d))+))
```

This expression gives me the error "Invalid lookbehind assertion encountered in regular expression".

What's wrong with the expression? It should be combined with exact capture expression, so to test it i used this expression (#1 + #2):

```
(?<=((((?<=\d)([-−,*\s]|(X·))(?=\d))|(\d))+))(.*+)
```

I tried to remove elements from the lookbehind until it gets to work, and it only works when it has only one element:

```
(?<=(\d))(.*+)
```

It gives an error even if a quantifier is added to the `\d`. This doesnt work:

```
(?<=(\d+))(.*+)
```

How can i insert my regexp #1 in a lookbehind? I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

PS: the units is in Russian, so here's the text i use to test regexps:

```
9 192 631 770 Гц[15];
299 792 458 м/с[15];
6,022 14X·1023 моль−1;
540·1012 Гц
1 мкм-
1 мкм
1мкм
1&#160;мкм
12 мкм
12мкм
12&#160;мкм
500 647 м
500 647м
12 нм
12нм
12&#160;нм
12 сс
```

Update: the final and working version of regex:

```
((((?<=\d)([-−,*·\s]|(X·))(?=\d))|(\d))+)\K(.{0,10}?)(?=(((?<=\d)|(?<=\b))(моль|мкм|мф|нм|лм|кг|кд|Гц|Кл|К|Дж|Вт|м|с|ф|А)(?=\b)))
```

All the changes was made is that i changed the structure of expression from this:

```
(?<=(1))(2)(?=(3))
```

To this:

```
(1)\K(2)(?=(3))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind/2462/simulating-variable-length-lookbehind-with-k#t=201608171026507447766 might help you :)

Comment: Boost regex does not support infinite width lookbehind, and you actually do not need it as you can just put your pattern and then use `\K` right after it.

Comment: Try `\d+(?:(?:[-−,*\s]|X·)\d+)*\K.{1,10}?(моль|мкм|мф|нм|лм|кг|кд|Гц|Кл|К|Дж|Вт|м|с|ф|А)\b` and replace with `$1` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/eB2oI1/1)).

Comment: Thanks! It worked with a slight modification: ((((?<=\d)([-−,*·\s]|(X·))(?=\d))|(\d))+\K)(.{0,10}?)(?=(((?<=\d)|(?<=\b))(моль|мкм|мф|нм|лм|кг|кд|Гц|Кл|К|Дж|Вт|м|с|ф|А)(?=\b)))

Comment: You placed `\K` inside your Pattern 1, it should be between. Also, why use so many capturing groups? `(?=\b)` = `\b`.

Comment: You mean (1)\K(2)(3) instead of (1\K)(2)(3) ?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. `\K` omits everything matched so far.

Comment: But it works, lol)

Comment: Because you omit several times. You can omit all once at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121155/discussion-between-lucifer63-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that Sublime Text regex is powered with Boost regex library that does not support infinite width lookbehind.

To mitigate that, Boost supports the `\K` operator that works like a positive lookbehind. Once the pattern on the left side of `\K` is matched, the `\K` discards it, starting to write newly matched text into a clear buffer.

Use the `PATTERN_1\KPATTERN_2(?=PATTERN_3)` scheme to replace with an empty string.